# Non-central Wishart as mixture of central Wisharts?

Tags: pr.probability

The non-central chi-square distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom has a density which can be expressed as
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c_i f_{\nu + 2i}(x),
$$
where $c_i$ is a function of the non-centrality parameter and $i$, and where $f_{j}(x)$ is the density of a chi-square distribution with $j$ degrees of freedom.  (*The non-central chi-squared distribution is a Poisson weighted mixture of central chi-squared distributions*).

My question is whether this property extends to the multivariate case, the non-central Wishart distribution: can we express the non-central Wishart as a weighted mixture of central Wishart distributions?

(My guess is not, except in the scalar case; if it does hold, however, and the $c_i$ are easy to compute, I would like to use this property to compute the moments of the non-central Wishart.)

Comment: It looks like Theorem 1 of [Li and Geng](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/STA-120017798) provides something like what I would need, for the case where the non-centrality matrix is rank 1.

Answer (score 1):

[arXiv:1512.08159](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08159) shows that the distribution of the scalar Schur complement in a noncentral Wishart matrix is a mixture of central chi-square distributions with different degrees of freedom. For the case of a rank-1 noncentrality matrix, the weights of the mixture representation arise from a noncentral beta mixture of Poisson distributions.

If the goal is to calculate the moments of the noncentral Wishart distribution, the graph representation of   [arXiv:0912.0577](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0577) seems convenient. (See also the tutorial [On the moment formulas for the noncentral Wishart distributions](http://mathlibre.org/wiki/index.php?plugin=attach&pcmd=open&file=kuriki-29june2010.pdf&refer=Osaka2010).)